# how to get nearby places using google places with python and flask

Tags: python, flask, google-places

i am trying to get nearby places using googleplaces with python and flask

i am getting this error: (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'place_name' referenced before assignment)

here is my code:

````
@app.route('/Search', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def Search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
            lat_lng={'lat':31.7917, 'lng' : 7.0926},
            radius=500,
            types=[types.TYPE_SHOPPING_MALL] or [types.TYPE_STORE])`

        if query_result.has_attributions:
            print(query_result.html_attributions)

        for place in query_result.places:
            place.get_details()
            place_name = place.name
            print(place.name)
            place_rating = place.rating
            print(place.rating)
            place_location = place.get_location
            print(place.get_location)
            for photo in place.photos:
                photo.get(maxheight=500, maxwidth=500)
                photo.mimetype
                photo.url
                photo.filename
                photo.data
            return render_template('Search.html', place_name, place_rating, place_location)
    else:
        return render_template('Search.html')```


#Note: i am new to python in general
````

Comment: I am guessing the error is due to code that is not shown maybe, have check of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error

Comment: hmm i tried your result but it didn't work, anyhow i have gotten an answer by @25 thansks for responding tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return render_template('Search.html', place_name, place_rating, place_location)
```

The above isn't valid syntax.  When you pass the details to the template, you need to do it as:

```
return render_template('Search.html', name = place_name,
                        rating = place_rating, location = place_location)
```

The variables `name`, `rating` and `location` will then be accessible in the template as `{{name}}`, `{{rating}}` and `{{location}}`.

However, the way you have the for loops laid out means the first time the return statement is reached, it will stop the loop and return the template with these variables.

Perhaps this is what you want, but you may wish to pass `query_result` to the template, and implement a Jinja2 for loop in the template to print out the various place details.   You would remove the for loops and replace that whole block with:

```
return render_template('Search.html', all_places = query_result)
```

Then in the template something like:

```
{% if all_places %}
{% for place in all_places %}
    <p><b>{{place.name}}</b> has a rating of <u>{{place.rating}}</u></p>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No places found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you so much, you fixed my problem now the thing is i tried too many times so i can't know for sure if i am returning any results because of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.

Comment: Looking at your sample code, I'm assuming you're using `https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places` which appears to be quite out of date.  You may wish to switch to the offical version at https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python.

Comment: hmmm i didn't know that there was a updated version thanks for letting me know i'll take a look and change my code right away.

Comment: okay so i tried implementing the 'official version' i have gotten this code but it didn't work: https://pastebin.com/MSrS2Mvg

Comment: Please spin up a separate question, as this is a slightly different issue.

Comment: :/ i can't post a new question because someone didn't like my title and gave minus rep which blockes me from asking questions for 1 day, and i am in need of a solution so bad.